# HOWTO: Consuming ToolStripMenuItem.DropDownItemClicked in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, event-handling, contextmenustrip, toolstripmenu

I have a toolStripMenuItem which is a menu containing other dropdown items. When DropDownItemClicked event is raised by selection one of the dropdown items I  would like to consume the event if some condition is satisfied, like below:

```
Private Sub tsmi_DropDownItemClicked( _
        ByVal sender As Object, _
        ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItemClickedEventArgs) _
        Handles tsmi.DropDownItemClicked


        ...

        If some_condition_is_satisfied then
           e.Cancel = True <------ Cancel is not available in this event!
        End If

        ...
End Sub
```

The problem is that DropDownItemClicked does not provided the posibility to perform:

```
e.Cancel = True
```

So how could I consume this event?

Comment: If you could cancel, wouldnt that make it look like it is broke?  Can you just disable some sub items when a condition is met?

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to terminate the sub, then

```
If some_condition_is_satisfied then
    exit sub
End If
```

would do the trick - even in event handlers. However, if you want the program to be notified if the sub is cancelled then you will need to declare a boolean variable that has a class level scope and set he variable to false at the beginning of the sub and in the `If..Then` condition, set it to true.